# How to find greater than value of column 4

Tags: shell

How can I find greater than value of column 4 and print the whole line ? 
My output is a status report of a storage box.
eg:

```
Source                     Destination                   State          Lag         Status
host1:SystemState          backup1:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx     Snapvaulted    11:24:21    Idle
host2:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx    backup2:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx     Snapvaulted    1898:58:16  Idle
host3:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx    backup3:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx     Snapvaulted    18:58:02    Idle
host4:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx    backup4:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx     Snapvaulted    19:46:24    Idle
host5:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxxr   backup5:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxxr    Snapvaulted    5009:22:26  Idle
```

I have tried the following command :

`ssh backupFiler snapvault status | awk '{print $4}'| cut -d ':' -f 1 | awk '{ if ( $1 > 24 ) print $0 }'`

- Problem is I get only the 4th column as output

`ssh backupFiler snapvault status | awk '{ if ( $4 > 24 ) print $0 }'`

- Output is not accurate as the column is being considered as a string.

I need my output to show only the lines that have Lag greater than 24hrs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
ssh backupFiler snapvault status | awk '$4+0 > 24'
```

Adding zero to a variable is an AWK idiom for coercing it from a string to a numeric value.

#### Output:

```
host2:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx    backup2:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx     Snapvaulted    1898:58:16  Idle
host5:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxxr   backup5:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxxr    Snapvaulted    5009:22:26  Idle
```

Answer (score 1):

how about pipe your ssh output to:

```
awk -F':|\\s*' '$6>24'
```

with your current example, it ouputs:

```
host2:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx    backup2:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxx     Snapvaulted    1898:58:16  Idle
host5:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxxr   backup5:/vol/xxxxx/xxxxxxr    Snapvaulted    5009:22:26  Idle
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
awk '{split($4,a,":");if(a[1])>24{print}}'
```

so your command will be:

```
ssh backupFiler snapvault status | awk '{split($4,a,":");if(a[1])>24{print}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have first selected only column 4 with the first `awk`, if you need the full line, 
then you need to filter it differently, consider this :

```
 ssh backupFiler snapvault status |perl -ne ' print if (m/\b(\d+):\d+:\d+\b/ and  $1>24)'
```

Comment: Can u please explain this command perl -ne ' print if (m/\b(\d+):\d+:\d+\b/

Comment: sure, I am getting the numeric part (column 4), with the regex `\d+:\d+:\d+` - i.e 3 groups of digits seperated by `:`, and capturing the first one with `()` - saved to `$1`, finally, the regex is bounded with `\b` (doesnt fall within some other field). Then compare `$1` with `24`, if this whole expression succeeds, `print` it. Perl is terse! :)